# How to generate series in a graph automatically using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have written vba code for generating the graph by button click. It is working correctly, but the problem is I want to add more series.

My code is

```
Dim ch As Chart
Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set ch = ch.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, name:=assume)
With ch
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
 With .Parent
  .Top = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Top
  .Left = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Left
  .name = "ch"
 End With
End With
Dim sh As Series
 Set sh = ch.SeriesCollection(1)
  With sh
 .Values = Columns(b).Offset(0, 0)
 .XValues = Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)
 End With
```

Here `assume` is the variable which holds the sheet name.. and in `columns(b)`, `b` is variable which holds the column name.

If I click the button it will generate the graph and if clicked the button  second time it will generate the graph again.

I want that graph line in first graph only I don't want to create multiple graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break this up into two separate codes, 1 to create the original chart, another to add series as you go along.

```
'===== First Chart Run ============

Dim ch As Chart
Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set ch = ch.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=assume)

With ch

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    With .Parent
        .Top = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Top
        .Left = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Left
        .Name = "ch"
    End With

End With

Dim sh As Series
Set sh = ch.SeriesCollection(1)

With sh
    .Values = Columns(b).Offset(0, 0)
    .XValues = Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)
End With

'===== Add More Series ============

Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts("ch")
ch.SeriesCollection.Add _ 
    source:=assume.Range(Columns(b).Offset(0,0),Columns(b).Offset(0,-2))
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line  "" ch.SeriesCollection.Add _ 
    source:=assume.Range(Columns(b).Offset(0,0),Columns(b).Offset(0,-2)""

Comment: OKAY,
I made it correct You missed one bracket there
and one more thing
for "Columns(b).Offset(0,-2)" it is selecting entire column 
I just want to select column starting from second cell for example 
selecting column A from second cell

Comment: Please explain more clearly exactly what you want your range to be. Either that, or just adjust the code to find the range you are after. I can't understand, at this moment, `selecting column A from second cell`

Comment: Columns(b).Offset(0,0).. here assume that b has value "A" then it will select entire column..from starting
soo I want to select the column A from second row

Comment: So change ... `Range(Columns(b).Offset(0,0),Columns(b).Offset(0,-2))` to `Range(Range(Columns(b) & "2"), Range(Columns(b) & Rows.Count)`

Comment: Hello Scott,
I didnt get it Can you please explain me for this code:

    .Values = Columns(b).Offset(0, 0)
        .XValues = Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN -> that was code you provided in your OP. It sets your chart values to the whole of `Column(b)` and the X-Axis Values to the whole of `Column(b)` offset to columsn to the left.